# python: filter objects from a list with dict fields

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have python script which is generated data (dict) objects in below format. All are in single quotes saperated by commas.

```
['a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1', 'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1, e:e1', 'a:a1, b:b1']
```

For better visibility it looks like this

```
[
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1', 
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1, e:e1', 
'a:a1, b:b1'
]
```

I want to filter this with dict fields which are started with any fields specified from below 'x' variable.

```
x = [b, c, d]
```

Required output is filtering all other elements except the one's specified in above lists.

```
['b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1, c:c1', 'b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1']
```

Again for better visibility:

```
[
'b:b1, c:c1, d:d1',    ## first row a eliminated
'b:b1, c:c1',          ## second row a eliminated
'b:b1, c:c1, d:d1',    ## third row a, e eliminated
'b:b1'                 ## fourth row a eliminated
]
```

I have already tried below.

```
import re

data = ['a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1', 'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1, e:e1', 'a:a1, b:b1']
x = ["b", "c", "d"]
data = data_2 = [(','.join(item.split(",")[1:]).strip()) for item in data]
print([re.sub(f"[^{''.join(x)}]:\w+, ", '', s) for s in data])


new = ['a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1', 'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1, e:e1', 'a:a1, b:b1']
new = new_2 = [(','.join(item.split(",")[1:]).strip()) for item in new]
y = {'b', 'c', 'd'} #use a set here instead for performance
print([','.join(d for d in s.split(',') if d[0] in y) for s in new])

#output
['b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1, c:c1', 'b:b1, c:c1, d:d1, e:e1', 'b:b1']
['b:b1', 'b:b1', 'b:b1', 'b:b1']
```

I am new to python.. please help.

Comment: In `python` a dictionary is defined with `{key: value}`. There are no `{}`s in your list. Are you sure it's a dictionary, or is it just a string that looks partly like a dictionary?

Comment: You might be better just making them dictionaries with `json.loads(f'{{{element}}}')` and then doing as you wish

Comment: You should also show your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.sub` in a list comprehension:

```
x = ['b', 'c', 'd']
result = [re.sub(f"[^{''.join(x)}]:\w+,? ?", '', s) for s in data]
```

Or use a nested comprehension that uses `str.split`:

```
x = {'b', 'c', 'd'} #use a set here instead for performance
result = [','.join(d for d in s.split(',') if d[0] in x) for s in data]
```

Results:

```
['b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1, c:c1', 'b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1']
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. i have tried your suggested script, only change i observe is i am getting e:e1 also, which is not required.. Not sure if i have done any mistake.. please see my updated question.

Comment: I fixed the regex, I didn’t consider matches at the end of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
data = [
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1', 
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1, e:e1', 
'a:a1, b:b1'
]

x = ["b", "c", "d"]
print([" ".join(j for j in i.split() if any(n in j for n in x)).rstrip(",") for i in data])
#or
print([" ".join(j for j in i.split() if any(j.startswith(n) for n in x)).rstrip(",") for i in data])
```

**Output:**

```
['b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1, c:c1', 'b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
data  = [
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1', 
'a:a1, b:b1, c:c1, d:d1, e:e1', 
'a:a1, b:b1'
]

x = ['b', 'c', 'd']

data_2 = [','.join(filter(lambda i: i.strip()[0] in x, item.split(','))).strip() for item in data]

print(data_2)
```

Result:

```
['b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1, c:c1', 'b:b1, c:c1, d:d1', 'b:b1']
```

Comment: This does not result in the same output as OP desired.